# Send notification to be received on TFS Get Latest Version

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013

We are using TFS on Visual Studio 2013.  When our developers Get Latest Version (GLV) and there is a new db script file received, it is stored under a specific folder, to be run using our custom update app.

What I want is that upon doing a GLV, they get a notification (in Visual Studio) that there are new scripts to run to update the db (generically speaking, that a new file has been added under a certain path).

Is there a way to achieve this with TFS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a visual studio extension, to be triggered on Get Latest, which would check a certain path within source control, you would have to roll this to all of your developers and would either have to store the lookup paths centrally or redeploy the app if the look up paths changed.

Alternatively you could add a bat / powershell script to your source control. within this script you could do the get latest and also run any scripts that you would like to run. you would then get the developers to get the latest against this script and then run it, which would get the rest of the files and would also run the db scripts.

Answer (score 1):

It will not give you exactly what you want, but you can use built in [TFS alerts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181334.aspx) to notify you or the team when a file is **checkedin** under a folder with a specific name/specified path/file extension.

[image: New Alert Template]

Comment: Close but no cigar ;)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want your users to be running their locally built solutions against the latest database version to keep everyone in sync. Why not just use the usual workflow to procure 'notifications' in the form of build output?

I've dealt with this in the past, and the best solution I've come up with is to write a custom MSBuild target for 'BeforeBuild' into each of the projects that rely on the database being updated. The MSBuild target checks the version of the database installed (You would have to come up with a means for doing so, it can be tricky!).

If the currently deployed database does not match the version in the scripts you have just synced to, a build event could be raised. When the versions match the target would output a success message (or maybe nothing at all), and if the versions do not match the target would issue a build Warning or build Error depending on the severity of change observed (it might depend for you insofar as Major/Minor version variance is considered).